# Running Lines on Rich Text Area in Trigger

Tags: trigger, custom-field

We have a requirement that we should display running lines in Case comments , instead of a standard one.

Am planning to Copy Rich Text field (Case Comments) values to another rich text field values to display the running lines.

Below is my code:

```
trigger CEP_Case_Comment_Trigger on CEP_Case_Comments__c (before insert, before update) {

    for(CEP_Case_Comments__c caseComm :trigger.new){
        caseComm.CEP_Case_Comments_Formula__c = '<marquee>'+ '<B>'+ caseComm.CEP_Case_Comments__c  + '<B>'+'</marquee>';

        caseComm.CEP_Case_Comments_Formula_Text__c =  '<marquee>'+ '<B>' + caseComm.Case_Comments_Formula_Text_Area__c  + '<B>'+ '</marquee>';  
    }
}
```

The HTML Tag `<marquee>` is not working with Trigger, but the tag `<B>` is working.
Please help.

Comment: Can you please shade some more light on "working and not working" tags. Are they saved in the system? Generating error during parsing or runtime?

Comment: Hello Mahmood, am using only <marquee> and <B> tag. Yes am using in Trigger. No error is generating.  Am not getting the running lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rich text fields only support a very limited subset of all html tags. Marquee is not one of them. Unsupported tags are automatically deleted. You can find the full list of supported tags here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_using_html_editor.htm&type=5

As a side note, the marquee tag has been marked obsolete, so you may wish to stop using it where possible: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: I do not miss the marquee-laden early 2000's of the Internet.

Comment: @sfdcfox hahaaha. I had to look it up to remind me what it does. I might start using it again for the nostalgic value. They were simpler (and uglier times).

Comment: CSS animations rendered marquee obsolete. I'm not even sure modern browsers would do anything other than treat it as a normal span element.

Comment: @sfdcfox It still works in Chrome! And after having looked at it for a minute my nostalgia has vanished....